# Google-Sheets number of rows it takes to find a >= value to

Tags: google-sheets, match, row, formula

[image]

I have this dataset in google sheets.
I am looking for a formula that shows the number of rows it takes to get to a value >= the value on that row.
So the first value we check is 10, the result should be 4 since it takes 4 rows to find a value >=10.
For the 2nd row the value is 9 there, it takes 3 rows to find a value which is >=9. and so on.

Can someone give me such a formula?

I'm stuck in formula's like=
=IFERROR(MATCH(TRUE, A1:A5 >= 10, 0), COUNTIF(A1:A5, "<10") + 1)

Comment: What if there's another value **10** in Cell_A6; will ***Cell_A1→10*** go for an `exact match` in ***Cell_A6→10*** OR `nearest match` in ***Cell_A5→11***

Answer (score 2):

This should work...

```
=let(checkRng,A2:A,zValue,A1,
 Min(filter(row(checkRng),if(checkRng<>"",checkRng>=zValue,false)))-row())
```

[image]

Comment: @Emiel, glad it works, would you mind clicking the 'accept` button as that fuels my sense of meaning us StackOveflowers to continue to help others.